# Assign a text file to a js variable?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to assign a file like "info.txt" to a js variable so i can then set it to a div's inner html ?

This is currently what i have:

```
texts = //load content of a text file (text file contains the html etc)
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = text; //assign
```

Then i would have:

```
<div id="main">//content shows here</div>
```

Is this possible ? I should mention i am not using a library. I want to learn to do it without one. Also does the text file require a set permissions type? And will it display HTML layout or just show it as text?

EDIT: The text file is on the same server :)

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem using javascript.

Comment: The question does not seem to say one way or the other. Are you trying to load the file from the user's computer, or does it reside on the server?

Comment: The file is on the same server :)

Comment: If it is on the server, you can get it via an ajax call. The ActiveX case is only for files on the user's machine.

Comment: Will it use HTML as just text though or will the HTML be used with my CSS file ?

Comment: If you use innerHTML, it will show up as HTML.

Comment: Could you make an answer so i can tick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is on the server, you can get it via an ajax call.

The ActiveX case is only for files on the user's machine.

If you use `innerHTML`, it will show up as HTML.